# un-resolve a resharper conflict with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I am using `VS 2012` with `Resharper 7`. I had resolved a conflict for a VS command and now I want to undo it.

That is, I want to use the Resharper command for that particular command. I am not asking about changing the whole scheme.

[This link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_ReSharper__Resolving_Keyboard_Shortcut_Conflicts.html) only informs on how to resolve a new conflict. What about a conflict that I had resolved earlier and now I want to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to just re-assign it manually the way you would set up any other keyboard shortcut.  Go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard` to set up the shortcuts.  All Resharper commands start with "Resharper", so type that in the box under "Show commands containing:".  At that point you just need to find the command you want and set the keyboard command for use in "Text Editor".

Answer (score 0):

You can reapply the ReSharper keyboard shortcut bindings in the options dialog (Environment → Keyboard & Menus) and hitting "Apply shortcuts".

Comment: That would change the short cut scheme. Not un-resolve the conflict that I had resolved earlier.. I would like to reassign the individual action or keyboard combination...

Comment: In that case, just edit the shortcuts as normal, as Patrick states in his answer.